# Issues with python quad limit option

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy quad and I am clearly misunderstanding the documentation associated with the limit options. I want to limit the number subintervals my function is evaluated on in order to decrease by run time. I put together a short example to illustrate my confusions.

```
def func(x):
    print x
    return x

quad(func,0,10,limit=4)
```

I expect 4 x values to be printed, but instead I get 21. Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
William

Answer (score 1):

The `limit` keyword controls the number of adaptive subintervals, but not directly the number of evaluations. Namely, QUADPACK probably uses a higher-order quadrature that evaluates the function several times per each interval. The number of evaluations is also not necessary divisible by 4, since the routine can possibly do some additional evaluations.

For details, see the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadpack/dqagse.f#L43)

Answer (score 0):

The prints seem to come from you `func` function not the `quad`. `quad` simply returns.

Try like this instead, if you want to print the result:

```
def func(x):
    return x

print quad(func, 0, 10, limit=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a mistake, the result of quad is :

```
In [30]: a = quad(func,0,10,limit=4)
5.0
0.130467357414
9.86953264259
0.674683166555
9.32531683344
1.6029521585
8.3970478415
2.83302302935
7.16697697065
4.25562830509
5.74437169491
0.021714184871
9.97828581513
0.349212543221
9.65078745678
1.09591136707
8.90408863293
2.18621432666
7.81378567334
3.52803568649
6.47196431351

In [31]: a
Out[31]: (50.0, 5.551115123125783e-13)
```

Just remove the `print` statement in your function and print `quad`.